# MySQL: query with two many to many relations and duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, inner-join

I have four models: `articles`, `authors` and `tags`. Each article can have many authors, and also can have many tags.

So my DB will have the following tables:

```
`article`
`article_author`
`author`
`article_tag`
`tags`
```

Here in MySQL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS article_tag;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS article_author;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS author;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tag;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS article;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS author (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tag (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tag VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article_author (
  article_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  author_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (article_id, author_id),
  INDEX fk_article_author_article_idx (article_id ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX fk_article_author_author_idx (author_id ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_article_author_article
    FOREIGN KEY (article_id)
    REFERENCES article (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_article_author_author
    FOREIGN KEY (author_id)
    REFERENCES author (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article_tag (
  article_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  tag_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (article_id, tag_id),
  INDEX fk_article_tag_article_idx (article_id ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX fk_article_tag_tag_idx (tag_id ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_article_tag_article
    FOREIGN KEY (article_id)
    REFERENCES article (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_article_tag_tag
    FOREIGN KEY (tag_id)
    REFERENCES tag (id)
);
```

And we can insert some data in our DB:

```
INSERT INTO article (id, title) VALUES (1, 'first article'), (2, 'second article'), (3, 'third article');
INSERT INTO author (id, name) VALUES (1, 'first author'), (2, 'second author'), (3, 'third author'), (4, 'fourth author');
INSERT INTO tag (id, tag) VALUES (1, 'first tag'), (2, 'second tag'), (3, 'third tag'), (4, 'fourth tag'), (5, 'fifth tag');
INSERT INTO article_tag (article_id, tag_id) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 1), (3, 2);
INSERT INTO article_author (article_id, author_id) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4);
```

Now I want to retrieve the articles, and for every article I want the related author ids as well as tag ids:

```
SELECT 
  article.id, 
  article.title,
  JSON_ARRAYAGG(author.id) AS authors,
  JSON_ARRAYAGG(tag.id) AS tags
FROM article
INNER JOIN article_author ON article.id = article_author.article_id
INNER JOIN author ON article_author.author_id = author.id
INNER JOIN article_tag ON article.id = article_tag.article_id
INNER JOIN tag ON article_tag.tag_id = tag.id
GROUP BY article.id;
```

This is returning duplicates. Is not due to `JSON_ARRAYAGG` (we can replace if to `COUNT` and duplicates will still be there), but due to the double relation in the same query: if we remove either tags or authors from the query, the duplicates will dissapear. But I really would like to be able to be able to query multiple relations in same query.

How can I avoid those duplicates?

Comment: Well asked, but you should [edit] the question and add your desired result with the sample data in tabular text form.

Comment: I see no duplicates:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d14756567b446cfc2fa8488382ff9963.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the duplicates are in the author array as well as in the tags array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you mean duplicates in the JSON fields.  The problem is that you are joining along two different dimensions, so you get a Cartesian product for each article.

With some aggregation functions, you can just use `DISTINCT` to get around this.  That option is not available for the JSON functions.  Instead, you can use subqueries:

```
SELECT a.id, a.title,
       (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(aa.author_id)
        FROM article_author aa 
        WHERE a.id = aa.article_id 
       ) as authors,
       (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(art.tag_id)
        FROM article_tag art
        WHERE a.id = art.article_id 
       ) as tags
FROM article a;
```

Note that because you are only including the ids, you do not need to join to the base tables -- `authors` and `tags`.  Of course, you can do that in the subquery if you want, but it is unnecessary.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=03d77e089de01bbe84c1d37dc6b8e319) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hm, I see… what if I wanted to retrieve other fields apart of the ids? I just tried using JSON_ARRAYAGG with JSON_OBJECT, but as you said we don't have other fields available.

Comment: I'll ask this in another question, as this is correct