# MySQL: query with two many to many relations and duplicates, with double intermediate table

Tags: mysql, join, many-to-many

This question is about selecting data across many-to-many relations in MySQL. Is related to another two questions, but with some differences:

- [MySQL: query with two many to many relations and duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62861992/mysql-query-with-two-many-to-many-relations-and-duplicates)
- [MySQL: query with two many to many relations and duplicates, with full data from subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62862293/mysql-query-with-two-many-to-many-relations-and-duplicates-with-full-data-from/62862355#62862355)

Those questions used a simple mockup database with simple many to many relations:

```
article
article_author
author
article_tag
tag
```

Now I will introduce next level of complexity. We want each author to be able to tag each of *their* articles. Thus, we will connect `tags` to the intermediate table `article_author` instead of to author directly.

```
article
article_author
author
article_author_tag
tag
```

Here is in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `article` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `author` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
);

CREATE TABLE `tag` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `article_author` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `article_id` int NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_index` (`author_id`,`article_id`),
  KEY `fk_article_author_author1_idx` (`author_id`),
  KEY `fk_article_author_article1_idx` (`article_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_article_author_article1` FOREIGN KEY (`article_id`) REFERENCES `article` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_article_author_author1` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `author` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `article_author_tag` (
  `article_author_id` int NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`article_author_id`,`tag_id`),
  KEY `fk_article_author_tag_article_author1_idx` (`article_author_id`),
  KEY `fk_article_author_tag_tag1_idx` (`tag_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_article_author_tag_article_author1` FOREIGN KEY (`article_author_id`) REFERENCES `article_author` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_article_author_tag_tag1` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tag` (`id`)
); 


INSERT INTO article (id, name) VALUES (1, 'first article'), (2, 'second article');
INSERT INTO `author` (id, name) VALUES (1, 'first author'), (2, 'second author');
INSERT INTO tag (id, name) VALUES (1, 'first tag'), (2, 'second tag');
INSERT INTO article_author (author_id, article_id) VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1);
INSERT INTO article_author_tag (article_author_id, tag_id) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2);
```

And now, I want just to select the tags that authors of an article used to tag it, as a JSON array; but I can't get rid of duplicates:

```
SELECT
  JSON_ARRAYAGG(tag.id)
FROM article_author
JOIN article_author_tag ON article_author_tag.article_author_id = article_author.id
JOIN tag ON article_author_tag.tag_id = tag.id
WHERE article_author.article_id = 1;
```

Here it is in a db<>fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=253f30ecd2f87b06c3894ef02b2ee35d

Any idea how can I get rid of them?

---

**Edit:**
I can do it with CONCAT and GROUP_CONCAT, and then casting to JSON. But it looks quite hacky:

```
SELECT
   CAST(CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag.id SEPARATOR ','), ']') AS JSON) AS tags
FROM article_author
JOIN article_author_tag ON article_author_tag.article_author_id = article_author.id
JOIN tag ON article_author_tag.tag_id = tag.id
WHERE article_author.article_id = 1;
```

Here it is in a db<>fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=20087a9036acb00637be8d2f58747ba5

Any other idea will be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `distinct` functionality for json yet (something like `JSON_ARRAYAGG(distinct tag.id)`), but there is a common workaround for it:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_OBJECTAGG(tag.id,tag.id),"$.*")
FROM article_author
JOIN article_author_tag ON article_author_tag.article_author_id = article_author.id
JOIN tag ON article_author_tag.tag_id = tag.id
WHERE article_author.article_id = 1;
```

`JSON_OBJECTAGG` works as an implict distinct, because json tags are distinct by definition, so adding `{"1": 1}` twice results in just one of those remaining. Afterwards, you `JSON_EXTRACT` just the values to get the format you intended (e.g. without the artificially added tags).

Another method would be to feed the json function with the already correct, distinct data:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(id) 
FROM (
  SELECT distinct tag.id
  FROM article_author
  JOIN article_author_tag 
  ON article_author_tag.article_author_id = article_author.id
  JOIN tag ON article_author_tag.tag_id = tag.id
  WHERE article_author.article_id = 1
) subquery;
```

You first prepare the data the way you want it (e.g. the distinct tag-ids), then use `JSON_ARRAYAGG` to format your output.